# How should "Advertencia" be translated as a section appearing at the start of a book?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

I am reading "Los Indios" by Antonio Batres Jáuregui; the book begins with a section marked "ADVERTENCIA"

A translation of this word appears to be "Warning" or "Caveat", but I reckon there's probably a more accurate translation to convey the meaning.

The section is short, and is:

*El carácter severo de la historia me ha obligado, al escribir este
libro, á procurar que las noticias que contiene, vayan apoyadas por
la autoridad de escritores notables, que he leído con detenimiento,
y que cito á cada paso, no por hacer alarde vano de erudición, sino
para justificar las aseveraciones que modestamente presento al
público, aunque con la plena confianza de haber tenido á la vista, al
formularlas, una gran parte de las obras que arrojan luz sobre los
tiempos pasados de la raza indígena de América.*

So what would be a better translation for "Advertencia" here than "Caveat" or "Warning"?

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer because a native English speaker may be more suited to distinguish the finest differences between synonyms, but I like how «advisory notice» sounds. Does this fit into what you were thinking?

Comment: Yes, "Advisory" makes sense, but I wonder if there's something yet a little more precise; something like "Note to the Reader" but hopefully less verbose.

Comment: I agree that a native english speaker, or at least somebody used to english books, could suggest a commonly used term, but I could suggest "Forewarning".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try `Foreword`. I would have favored "Note from the author", but as you say in the comments you want something less verbose.

Actually, the only example I can think of it right now is [Anathem, from Neal Stephenson](http://www.amazon.es/ANATEMA-NOVA-Neal-Stephenson/dp/8466641130), where he has a note for the reader and states that if the reader likes "hard" science fiction they can skip the note, and if not, there is something he wants to clarify.

Honestly, I would have maintained "warning", because the author could have very well said "Nota al lector", "prefacio", "preámbulo" or similar. If he wanted that statement to be an *advertencia* it should be kept as a "warning" for the English version.

Answer (score 1):

For a short statement like this, I favor "Author's Note," i.e. a short piece of information which the author considers useful to readers before  reading the book. It is a neutral term, whereas "Warning" or "Caveat" could be interpreted as negative, and I'm assuming no author wants to warn readers away. The Spanish "advertencia" is often used in the same way as the English word "warning," for example, "Advertencia: Alto Voltaje." It can also mean simply an advisory note. RAE lists one of the definitions of "advertencia" as "Escrito, por lo común breve, con que en una obra o en una publicación cualquiera se advierte algo al lector." In addition to "warn," the verb "advertir" can mean to draw attention to something, which is what the author of "Los Indios" is doing.

If an author has information to share which goes beyond a brief statement, then a longer piece--a preface--would be appropriate. A preface could include information about the origin and scope of the book, the author's methodology, etc. An introductory piece written by someone other than the author is called a foreword.